# how to append values to a state array in react

Tags: reactjs

How do I append new value to the state array ?

I tried,

```
const [diabled, setDisabled] = useState([]);

const getValue = (id) => {
...
...
...
setDisabled(...disabled,id)
}
```

But doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It should be spread inside an array:**

Also, correct your spelling: `disabled` not `diabled`

```
setDisabled([...disabled,id])
```

And change your useState:

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState([]);  // <-- Correct your spelling
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change it to:

```
 setDisabled([...disabled,id])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```js
setDisabled((prevState) => [...prevState,id])
```